# Unable to write an object to a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, io

After running `SaveToFile()` the file isempty. It won't print anything. Also, when I use `while(file.eof() == 0)` instead of `while(file.read(...))` in `DisplayFromFile()` it loops forever.

```
using namespace std;

void database::SaveToFile()
{
  fstream file;
  file.open("abc", ios::ate);
  for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
  {
    file.write((char *) &s[i], sizeof s[i]);
  }
  file.close();
}

void database::DisplayFromFile()
{
  student stud;
  fstream file;
  file.open("abc", ios::in);
  file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
  cout << "Rollno\t|\tMarks " << endl;
  cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;
  while (file.read((char *) &stud, sizeof stud))
  {
    cout << stud.getrollno() << "\t|\t" << stud.getmarks() << endl;
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Comment: Unless you only have plain data types, you will run into trouble reading and writing your data like that (i.e. a `std::string` or `std::vector` will be a problem).

Comment: How do you suggest I do it?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++)` should be `for(int i=0;i<count;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do this using streams:

1. Writing to file:

`int main () {
              std::fstream fs;
          fs.open ("test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
              fs << " more lorem ipsum";
              fs.close();
              return 0;
    }`

2. Reading from file:

`int main () {
      string line;
      ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
      if (myfile.is_open())
      {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
          cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
      }
      else cout << "Unable to open file";
      return 0;
    }`